# Updating a Spreadsheet in Google Docs

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I have a python script that takes a generated CSV and uploads it to Google Docs. It can upload it just fine, put I cannot seem to get it to replace the data, it returns an error I cannot find reference to.

Le Code:

```
import gdata.auth
import gdata.docs
import gdata.docs.service
import gdata.docs.data
import gdata.docs.client


email = 'admin@domain.com'
CONSUMER_KEY='domain.com'
CONSUMER_SECRET='blah54545blah'


ms_client = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient('Domain_Doc_Upload')
ms_client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.TwoLeggedOAuthHmacToken(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, email)

url = 'http://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/sd01blahgarbage'

ms = gdata.data.MediaSource(file_path="C:\\people.csv", content_type='text/csv')
csv_entry2 = ms_client.Update(url, ms)
```

It returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    csv_entry2 = ms_client.Update(ms, url)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\gdata\client.py", line 717, in update
AttributeError: 'MediaSource' object has no attribute 'to_string'
```

I cannot find anything about the 'to_string' attribute, so I am lost on the trace. ANy help, much appreciated.

Comment: Try this `ms = gdata.data.MediaSource(file_path="C:\\people.csv", content_type='text/csv')`. Take a look here http://tinyurl.com/88grdk6
`

Comment: Did not notice that, but, unfortunately, the same error.

Comment: This is the correct way `updated_entry = client.Update(entry, media_source=ms)`. So, try this `csv_entry2 = ms_client.Update(url,ms)
`

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at [official docs first](https://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html).

Comment: @RanRag it is now returning str object has no attribute 'to_string', so I get the feeling I am passing the wrong object to the client, I did look at the docs, I am still having issues, thats why I came here.

Comment: @Kevin I assume you want to call `to_string` to get a `str`. Now you don't have to!

Comment: according to the [api](https://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html#UpdatingReplaceContent) `ms_client.Update(...)` should get `Entry` and `MediaSource` rather than url `String` and `MediaSource`

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the docs and it looks like the Update method takes (entry, ms) where entry needs to be a gdata.docs.data.DocsEntry object.  You should be able to get the DocsEntry object by getting a feed from your client.

feed = client.GetDocList()